# Gridview Databinding method in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, gridview, c-sharp, databind

I know I have done something wrong so I need some suggestion about writing the below code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
            /*grid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
            grid.DataBind();*/

            GridView1.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<
                GridView1.DataBind();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = getAttachmentsData();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

I need to show list data to gridview and also the attachments, so I tried with databind two times but its not working...

My complete code looks like...

```
namespace GridView.GridEditLink
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class GridEditLink : WebPart
    {                   
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;


            GridView1.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
                GridView1.DataBind();


            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                dgvAttachments.DataSource = getAttachmentsData();
                dgvAttachments.DataBind();
            }
        }


        private void Bind_Data()
        {
            ////Bind to Session table
            //GridView1.DataSource = Session["GridView1"];
            //GridView1.DataBind();
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;


                GridView1.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        public class AttachmentsData
        {

            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string AttachmentTitle { get; set; }
            public string AttachmentURL { get; set; }
        }

        public List<AttachmentsData> getAttachmentsData()
        {
            List<AttachmentsData> AttachmentsData = new List<AttachmentsData>();
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb currentWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList lst = currentWeb.Lists["Employee"];
                    SPQuery sQuery = new SPQuery();
                    sQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending=\"False\" /></OrderBy>";
                    sQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Attachments\" />";
                    sQuery.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;
                    SPListItemCollection myColl = lst.GetItems(sQuery);
                    if (myColl.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem item in myColl)
                        {
                            if (item["Attachments"].ToString() == "True")
                            {
                                SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                                SPFolder folder = currentWeb.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders[lst.Title].SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[item.ID.ToString()];
                                foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
                                {
                                    AttachmentsData.Add(new AttachmentsData()
                                    {
                                        Title = item["Title"].ToString(),
                                        AttachmentTitle = file.Name.ToString(),
                                        AttachmentURL = currentWeb.Url + "/" + file.Url.ToString()
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            else if (item["Attachments"].ToString() == "False")
                            {
                                AttachmentsData.Add(new AttachmentsData()
                                {
                                    Title = item["Title"].ToString(),
                                    AttachmentTitle = "--",
                                    AttachmentURL = Page.Request.Url.ToString() + "#"
                                });
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return AttachmentsData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, If you do databind() two times, it will take later one only. So whatever you are getting from getAttachmentsData(); will be shown in gridview.

Comment: How could I do both in one time?

Comment: You will need  get/combine data in one datatable only. and then you can bind that datatable to gridview.

Comment: which type of data are you getting from **getAttachmentsData()** function? try to user [DataTable](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/datatable-in-C-Sharp/), that will make easy to insert your desired value in gridview.

Comment: Is you have two gridview on page? What error you are getting?

Comment: with two gridview it works, but I have to do it in one gridview..I have to show attachments in same gridview.

Comment: Hi Vikash, to combine two datatables you will need to have same column structure in both tables, but this not seems to be case looking at above code of yours. What you can do is to show list items in gridview and add attachment column as a hyperlink in that grideview, on clicking on attchement column, open another page as popup and show attachment related to that item in a separate gridview.